# CSS - Position image to the left + partly cut-off + responsive + Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

[image: example]

Trying to accomplish the above with Bootstrap.  Ie. an image, that's partly cut-off to the left, that resizes with the window, and stays in the left column.

Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <img src="img.png" class="hero-img">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
            Lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried the following CSS:

```
.hero-img {
    position: fixed;
    left: -150px;
}
```

However, as the screen gets resized, the image bleeds into the right column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the width of the image to 100% of the width of the container then give it a negative left margin to move it 'off-canvas'. You could also consider changing the margin to be a percent so it gets smaller as your window width changes.

CSS

```
.hero-img {
    margin-left:-150px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Live example: http://www.bootply.com/lF9VBcD1wz

Comment: Any way to do this without container-fluid class (ie. container)?

Comment: @mistermat Are you wanting it to extend outside the container or get cut-off? If you want it to get cut-off so it doesn't spill outside the container you can just add this CSS `.container { overflow-x:hidden; }`

Comment: @mistermat If you are wanting it to spill outside the container you need to shift your layout a bit. What you want is a mix of fluid and non-fluid behavior, so you will need to position the image absolutely outside of a column element. Here is a live example: http://www.bootply.com/diTKVVZ65U